# Simplest way of explaining Pi is an irrational number

Tags: proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

I understand that, an irrational number can't be expressed as a fraction.

Pi is one of those number, that it is an irrational number.

**Can someone explain in the simplest way if possible, how to show that pi is an irrational number?**

I have read all those proofs but can't seem to understand any of it.

Comment: "I have read all those proofs..." *What* proofs? There are [6 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational), as well as numerous others around the internet. Your question is missing a lot of context.

Comment: And notice how the first answer was a proof that you've already read but don't understand. This is why it's important to actually explain what research you've done and what *specifically* you have trouble with....

Comment: "*Get it!!!!*" ............... you know, we could say the same thing right back to you.  If the linked proofs in user296602's comment or in Dietrich's answer aren't satisfactory to you, it is unlikely that *any* proof would be satisfactory to you.  It is quite probable that if you do not understand the linked proofs that you are not mathematically mature enough to understand or appreciate the concepts.  You might try coming back to this problem after a few more years of study.

Comment: Never use alone the tags of proof-explanation, proof-verification or similar. On the other hand, whenever you use the tag proof-explanation include the proof(s) that you want to understand.

Comment: I was merely quoting you.  If you feel that my comment was out of line, then that implies that you were out of line first.  If you are upset instead about referring to "mathematical maturity," this is a common phrase.  Having low mathematical maturity is not in and of itself a bad thing, it can be remedied through study.  I was not calling you unintelligent, I just saying that you are likely not ready and have not studied enough of the prerequisite material yet necessary to understand the proofs.

Comment: thank you sorry, I got my answer.

Comment: @123 Usually, irrationality proofs are extremely difficult! For example, it is UNKNOWN, whether $\color\red {\pi+e}$ is rational. The simplest proof for $\pi$ should be the representation as an infinite continued fraction based on the continued fraction of the $\arctan$-function. A proof as easy as the $\sqrt{2}$-irrationality proof probably does not exist.

Comment: I am glad I didn't study maths. All these staff seem crazy.

Comment: The standard proof that $e$ is irrational is easier and you may like that better, it also gives insight into summations with terms that vanish rapidly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a really short proof by [I. Niven](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788). You will understand it. It is just one page, and it uses only elementary calculus. I think this is more or less the simplest proof possible.

Comment: I know of this proof, but it is not simple.

Comment: it doesn't to be rigous

Comment: @123 You cannot expect a proof of the irrationality of $\pi$ to be as simple as for $\sqrt 2$. Any proof will need to make use of properties of $\pi$, so usually use the special values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and the derivative/integral relation between these functions. With this in mind, I find it hard to imagine any really shorter proof than Niven's. -- Of coures, the formulatoin is purposefully terse. Maybe you can ask *specific* questions about specific points that are unclear to you...

Comment: aah thank you Mr Hagen Von Eitzen you have answered my question. I thought maybe there is a simple proof like $\sqrt{2}$